# How to turn off skimage warnings

Tags: warnings, scikit-image

I want to turn off skimage  UserWarning: I used this code but they are still enabled.

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    skimage.io.imsave
```

Comment: May be because skimage uses their own warning library... (?)
https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/io/_io.py

Comment: The code above worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 27):

I found in the documentation that there is a dedicated option "check_contrast" when **imsave** is called: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html?#imsave

If you want to disable imsave warnings indicating a low contrast image you should set this option to False: **check_contrast=False**

```
from skimage import io

io.imsave(filename, image, check_contrast=False)
```

Comment: `check_contrast=False` does the job.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently skimage uses imageio as his first plugin option to save an image.

Try to:

```
import imageio.core.util

def ignore_warnings(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

imageio.core.util._precision_warn = ignore_warnings
```

After that, you can save your image without the warnings:

```
imsave(filename, image)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me after nothing else worked